# Node.js wait until image has been uploaded and then render the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, module, callback

I'm using multiparty to upload an image to my web app's upload directory
the problem is that node doesn't wait for the image to be uploaded before displaying the page.

I have tried to make it work like this:

```
app.post('/home', uploadAvatar, function(req, res) {
            res.render('profile.ejs');  
});


function uploadAvatar(req, res, next) {
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.autoFiles    = true;
    form.uploadDir    = './public/uploads/';

    form.on('file', function(name,file){
        console.log( 'New file uploaded to ' + file.path );
    });

     form.on('part', function (part) {

     });

    form.on("close", function() {
        console.log('Upload completed!');
        return next();
    });

    form.parse(req);
}
```

But the form.on('close') is never called.

Comment: multiparty form does not emit a close event if there is an error, try listening for the error event

Comment: i checked it, no error occurs. Also i noticed that the close event fires if i add "part.resume();" in the part listener.